# Public/private key not generating - keychain access

Tags: macos, keychain

Keychain access - >certificate assistant -> request a certificate from a certificate authority -> save to disk -> save as .certSigningequest

Does not generate a public/private key chain, when I go to keys.

How do I solve this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Request a certificate from a certificate authority` creates a Certificate Signing Request, not a public/private key chain.   It will create the private key and store it in your key chain (as you named it), but the purpose of that command is to allow you to request a full X.509 certificate from an external Certificate Authority.

If you need to create just a public/private key pair, then it depends a bit on what you are planning on using it for.  For example, you can create an SSH public/private key pair by using `ssh-keygen`.

Similarly, you can create an RSA public/private key pair using the commands from [this answer from the security forum](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61622/openssl-generating-rsa-key-pair-public-key).

If, on the other hand, you're actually trying to create your own certificates, not just the public/private key pair, you can use `Keychain Access` to create a self-signed certificate using the `Create a Certificate` command.  That will contain the signature of your self-signed CA and the public key.